# AWS Sagemaker AttributeError: can't set attribute error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to python programming. Following the AWS learning path:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/?trk=el_a134p000003yWILAA2&trkCampaign=DS_SageMaker_Tutorial&sc_channel=el&sc_campaign=Data_Scientist_Hands-on_Tutorial&sc_outcome=Product_Marketing&sc_geo=mult

I am getting an error when excuting the following block (in conda_python3):

```
test_data_array = test_data.drop(['y_no', 'y_yes'], axis=1).values #load the data into an array
xgb_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv' # set the data type for an inference
xgb_predictor.serializer = csv_serializer # set the serializer type
predictions = xgb_predictor.predict(test_data_array).decode('utf-8') # predict!
predictions_array = np.fromstring(predictions[1:], sep=',') # and turn the prediction into an 
array
print(predictions_array.shape)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 test_data_array = test_data.drop(['y_no', 'y_yes'], axis=1).values #load the data into an array
> ----> 2 xgb_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv' # set the data type for an inference
> 3 xgb_predictor.serializer = csv_serializer # set the serializer type
> 4 predictions = xgb_predictor.predict(test_data_array).decode('utf-8') # predict!
> 5 predictions_array = np.fromstring(predictions[1:], sep=',') # and turn the prediction into an array

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

I have looked at several prior questions but couldn't find much information related to this error when it comes to creating data types.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just remove it then the prediction will work. Therefore, recommend removing this code line.
xgb_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv'

Answer (score 0):

Removing xgb_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv' will work.

But best way is that you first check the attributes of the object:

```
xgb_predictor.__dict__.keys()
```

This way, you will know that which attributes can be set.